# Динамический контент web-странички

Tags: html, javascript, php

Товарищи, подскажите, что следует использовать (технологию)? Верстаю трех-страничный сайт "Ремонт под ключ". На одной из страничек отображаются фото работ. Захотелось сделать эту загрузку динамичной - из папки с фотками в страницу. Я верстаю сайт впервые, вот и запутался, как это сделать, вернее даже чем? PHP? JavaScript? Я технологий не изучал - это первая работа. Просьба дать совет как сделать.И не ругать за вопросы, если показались неуместными.

Comment: > Я технологий не изучал

так изучите.

Comment: AJAX. Возможно, якорная навигация. Все зависит от степени «динамичности».

Answer (score 1):

В интернете есть наготовки галерей, который показывают несколько картинок, а другие скрыты. Не думаю что вам нужно много картинок показывать, поэтому воспользуйтесь методами из галерей). Если просто хотите менять, лучше всего это делается JSом.